# YouTubeAPI, same result is returned if a start-index is specified

Tags: youtube-api

**Original message**

> YouTube API の動画検索(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2)で
>   start-index を指定しても同じ結果が返されることがあります。
>
> feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=881
>
> feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=981
>
> 上記のようなAPIを実行すると、同じ結果が返されます。 原因を教えていただけますでしょうか？

---

**Translated message (by Google translate)**

> Video Search of YouTube API in
>   (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2) You might have the
>   same result is returned if you specify a start-index.
>
> feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=881
>
> feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=981
>
> When you run the API, such as described above, the same result is returned.
>   Could you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 3):

It should return error since the maximum allowed number of videos to return is now 500
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4282#c6

If you run the below (less than index 501), it will return you different results
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=481
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=15&start-index=381